# how to fixed scroll sidebar (Right/left) like facebook in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, scroll, sidebar

I am new in Angulajs and I have struggle and spend lots of time to build fixed right side directory.

Here are my features for fixed scroll directory.
1) If sidebar (Right/Left sidebar) is large then screen so it should not stick with screen until it reach to bottom.
2) Once we scroll down and reach to section bottom it should stick like glue in screen(fixed sidebar).
3) Same once we scroll bottom to top and we reach at actual bottom space of the section should normal scroll remaining part.

I want to contribute my code with you in answer I am giving answer.

Answer (score 1):

Required files
1) jQuery
2) Angularjs

directories.js

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('setClassWhenAtTop', function ($window) {
    var $win = angular.element($window); // wrap window object as jQuery object

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            if(!$(element).attr('style') )
            {
              $(element).width($(element).outerWidth());
              $(element).css('bottom',0);
            }

            var win_height = $(window).height();
            var topClass = attrs.setClassWhenAtTop; // get element's top relative to the document
            var offsetTop = $(element).offset().top



            $win.on('scroll', function (e) {

                var ele_height = $(element).height();
                if( ele_height > win_height )
                {

                  var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop();
                  var shouldFix = (offsetTop+ele_height)-(scroll_top+win_height);

                  console.log(shouldFix);
                  console.log(scroll_top +">="+offsetTop);

                  if( shouldFix < 0 && scroll_top >= offsetTop )
                  {
                    element.addClass(topClass);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    element.removeClass(topClass);
                  }
                }
                else
                {

                  if ( scroll_top >= offsetTop ) {
                      element.addClass(topClass);
                  } else {
                      element.removeClass(topClass);
                  }
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

How to use file..

Just put directory inside rightside/leftside bar like below.

```
set-class-when-at-top="p-f" where p-f{position:fixed;}
```

That means code will look like something

```
<div class="left">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
       <div class="width-100" set-class-when-at-top="p-f" >
sdfsfdfs
</div>
    </div>
```

Feel free to ask me any question.
Thanks,
Ronak Amlani.